# ftp_connect() not working when called from PHP from Flash

Tags: php, flash, ftp

I have a flash app and several PHP scripts.
I want to create a folder and upload images to it.

My php code resides in "http://dev.myapp.com.au/php/testFtp.php"
and my storage location is "storagetest.myapp.com.au"
These domains both exist on the same 'myapp' server.

Right now I just want to create the new folder.
In my PHP I'm using ftp_connect(), ftp_login() and ftp_mkdir().

This works fine when my test PHP is run from my browser but not when called from my Flash app. Here's part of my php script:

```
$ftp_server = "storagetest.myapp.com.au";
$ftp_user_name = "name";
$ftp_user_pass = "pass";
$dirNew = "/web/test/storage/new_folder";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$mk = ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dirNew);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

EDIT:

And how it is called from Flash:

```
sMyUrl = "http://dev.myapp.com.au/php/testFtp.php";
var myData:URLRequest = new URLRequest( sMyUrl );
myData.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
(set some vars here)
myData.data = variables; 
m_uloader = new URLLoader(); 
m_uloader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;  
m_uloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onRecordCompleteHandler); 
m_uloader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoErrorHandler); 
m_uloader.load(myData);
```

This flash code works for other PHP scripts.

I think I've tracked down the problem to ftp_connect(). When called from Flash and this is in the script the whole script stops working. Even my test echo statements are not returned.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?
Thanks :)

Comment: How exactly are you calling this script from your flash app?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the above comment.